# Use of verb to give is used alone or with preposition "to"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, indirect-objects

Why is it that when I say "I will give this book to my daughter",  I am using the verb "give" and the preposition "to", but "to" is not used in the following: "What kind of names do people in your culture give pets?"

Comment: It sounds like you need basic instruction in [*indirect objects*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)) and basic SVIO word-order in English. We have [lots of questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22indirect+object%22) about those here, too. You may wish to check out [**our sister site for English Language Learners**](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching **English as a foreign language”**, whereas here we’re more intended “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”

Comment: Strongly related, and possible duplicate of one or another of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1789 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/67846 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106857 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/90530 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107208 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95955 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/108310 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/116040 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77862 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/120773 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/117753 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/55331

Comment: I give my daughter this book, but I give this book to my daughter.

Answer (score 2):

English can be a flexible language at times, believe it or not.  Any of the following sentences is correct grammatically:

> 1) What kind of names do people in your culture give pets?
>
> 2) What kind of names do people in your culture give to pets?
>
> 3) I will give my daughter this book.
>
> 4) I will give to my daughter this book.
>
> 5) I will give this book to my daughter.

And there are probably many other combinations and permutations of word order that I could **give you** (or **give to you**), but I'll stop at five.  As for the reason why *your* two sentences have to be worded differently, I'll leave that to the grammarians.